# Disable cursor:pointer for labels of disabled checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox, css-selectors

I am trying to have `cursor:pointer` on my checkboxes and their labels.

Here's the code that I use - but I want to avoid having `cursor:pointer` on checkboxes and their labels that are `disabled`.

HTML looks like this:

```
<label>
    <input 
        type="checkbox"
        ...more attributes...
        > Yes, please specify:
</label>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox]:not([disabled]), 
label + input[type=checkbox]:not([disabled]) {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

The way I set it as disabled is using jQuery:

```
$("selector").prop("disabled", true);
$("selector").prop("disabled", false);
```

It seems I can't find a way to select `<label>` that contains a disabled checkbox.

Ideas?

Thank you.

Someone kindly provided a codepen for testing: http://codepen.io/8odoros/pen/BQVQGg

Comment: can you show a fiddle

Comment: where you set it as disabled ? can you explain more

Comment: You can not do this with css alone. You'd need a parent selector, which does not exist yet. The only css only way, would be to use separated label and input elements and alter their order, [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/8qhvp05n/), but you should ask your self if this is worth the trouble.

Comment: @TheodoreK. doesn't work when it's enabled

Comment: You're HTML suggests your CSS should be `label > input` but you have `label + input` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Don't know exactly what you need , is my understanding is right you need this

```js
$('button').click(function(){
var i = $('input');
    
    if ( i.is('[disabled]') ){
        i.attr('disabled',false)
    }else{
         i.attr('disabled',true);
    }
})
```

```css
input[type=checkbox][disabled]{
  cursor:default;
}
input[type=checkbox]:not([disabled]) +label {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" value="tasd" disabled />
<input type="text" value="text" disabled />
<button>disable/enable</button>

<input  type="checkbox" />
<label> This is enabled (pointer cursor)</label>
</br>
<input  type="checkbox"  disabled/> 
<label>This is disabled (default cursor)</label>
```

Comment: i just chaged  `cursor:none` to  `cursor:default`

Comment: I fail to see how this answer is related to the question at all.

Comment: No and I don't see any reason for it. You only posted a toggle disable attribute Javascript snippet, while the question was: select all labels that contain a disabled input. If there was a JS answer to the question it would look something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/4vmra2ja/). But if Op is ok with this, I don't mind.

Comment: nop the toggle is only for showing disable cursor working ,

Comment: if you copy the css and paste in your file , disabled check box  cursor will show the default

Comment: Yes, but not at the label, because it's not even in your answer. But like I said, just my few cents.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130087/discussion-between-jishnu-v-s-and-nico-o).

Comment: @Jishnu V S, Is it me or did you just copied my answer?

Comment: @TheodoreK. not really , i just want to show him, whats happening , you can check with mine i just added a disable only, sorry for the missunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

You can't select the parent (the label) with CSS. However, if you place the labels **after** the inputs you can then use  [Adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `+` like this:

```js
$("#active").prop("disabled", false);
$("#inactive").prop("disabled", true);
```

```css
input[type=checkbox]:not([disabled]) {
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=checkbox]:not([disabled]) +label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  type="checkbox" id="active"/>
<label> This is enabled (pointer cursor)</label>
</br>
<input  type="checkbox" id="inactive"/> 
<label>This is disabled (default cursor)</label>
```